# boostrap datetimepicker showing selecte date dropdown list

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using boostrap datetimepicker in my application and everything works well hower there is one issue when i click on the picker it shows a dropdown list of last selected date and the list keeps growing as i select new date and it end up covering the datetimepicker.
How can i disable the dropdown history list ?

Here is the configuration for my datetimepicker

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

       $('#dateDebut').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A',
                useCurrent: false,
                maxDate: new Date()
            });

});
```

Here is the screen shot of what it looks like [image]

Comment: In this case, what type of DOM element is #dateDebut?

Comment: It is a text type , this the markup : <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="dateDebut" placeholder="Sélectionez la date de début" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML, in the input, add the tag autocomplete="off", now, the INPUT will NOT show suggestions.

```
<input id="#datedebut" autocomplete="off" />
```

Definition by W3SCHOOLS:

> The autocomplete attribute specifies whether or not an input field should have autocomplete enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this attribute
`autocomplete = "off"` this will turn off the auto complete feature in the form element